# Emacs on Windows disable cmd

Tags: emacs

I've always used Emacs under Linux, but now I got a Windows machine and installed it.

However, every time I open Emacs it also opens a terminal (called cmd.exe on Windows, I think). Is there a way I can disable that terminal?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you get the Windows distribution of emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you got the GNU version of emacs for Windows from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/, there is an .exe called runemacs.exe.  Use that instead of emacs.exe.  "runemacs" will not pop up the annoying cmd window.