# Console window always appears when starting Emacs on Windows

Tags: windows, emacs

I noticed that when I run Emacs on Windows, it is always accompanied by a console window.

Does anyone know why this is? Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: You need to launch the `runemacs.exe` instead of `emacs.exe`.

Comment: That did the trick. Please create an answer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: I'm happy to help, but the question is essentially a duplicate and should probably be closed:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/10863526/2112489